# Why I haven't app-release.apk?

Tags: android

I follow [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) and I have done. Android Studio show "APK(s) generated successfully." But I haven't app-release.apk in floder /app (like in documentation) or floder /app/build/outputs/apk. Why?

**EDIT:**

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'alias'
        keyPassword 'passwordAlias'
        storeFile file('/path/file.jks')
        storePassword 'passwordFile'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company.project"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
*libs*
}
```

Comment: You will need to provide more details. There are wizards on this site but we don't have magical powers to answer something so vague. ༼∩✿ل͜✿༽⊃━☆ﾟ. * ･ ｡ﾟ

Comment: Exact steps to reproduce the error. What does your build.gradle file look like? Did you run a gradle task to `assembleRelease` or use the APK wizard?

Comment: Ok, I added build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

regenerate signed APK and check the output folder for where it is getting saved. Hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions 
        AndroidStudio->Build->Generate signed apk->Fill all detail->and your signed apk path is(yourprojectpath->app->app-release.apk

Comment: I still haven't app-release.apk.

Comment: and please check you application keystore would be same.

Comment: yes. I can't get apk file for this app, but other apps is ok.